# How to merge array in same indexing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have merge two array and i got following result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => year
    [1] => Month
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_question] => 88
            [question] => This is Question No. 1
            [question_type] => 3
            [answer_type] => option
            [question_level] => district
            [addedon] => 2017-07-23 19:15:26
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_question] => 87
            [question] => This is Question No. 2
            [question_type] => 3
            [answer_type] => text
            [question_level] => district
            [addedon] => 2017-07-16 00:45:19
        )
```

Now i want to get same index and remove everything except question like following

```
Array
    (
        [0] => year
        [1] => Month
        [2] => This is Question No. 1
        [3] => This is Question No. 2
     )
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way, but not tested

```
$expected_array=[];
foreach($your_2d_array as $k=>$v){

   if(is_array($v){
     $expected_array[$k] = $v['question']; 
   }else{
     $expected_array[$k] =$v;
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($expected_array);
echo "</pre>";
```